# how to send smtp mail in cakephp 2

Tags: email, smtp, cakephp-2.0

**What I did**

```
    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('me@mydomain.com' => 'test'),
        'host' => 'mail.mydomain.com',
        'port' => 80,
        'timeout' => 60,
        'username' => 'me@mydomain.com',
        'password' => 'me123',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => false,
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    );

    $email    = new CakeEmail('Smtp');
    $result   = $email->template('welcome_mail','default')
                       ->emailFormat('html')
                        ->to($to_email)
                        ->from('me@mydomain.com')
                        ->subject('Welcome')
                        ->viewVars($contents);

    if($email ->send('Smtp'))
    {   
        echo ('success');

    }
```

what I am doing wrong here?
Please can anyonce explain smtp settings here?
what is host,username,password,client?

**Please guide me what is host**

**which username and password I have to set here**

Answer (score 6):

I would add the Email Config to your email.php file located in **/app/Config/email.php** , if it doesn't exist **copy email.php.default to email.php,** Change the smtp settings there

```
public $smtp = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret'
);
```

**At the top of your Controller above class Controller extends AppController add,**

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

**Then to send an email, try**

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'))
    ->to('you@example.com')
    ->subject('About')
    ->send('My message');
```

To **test emails** what I usually do is send them to the Cake Logs,

**In /app/Config/email.php, include: ( The log output should be /app/tmp/logs/debug.log )

```
public $test = array(
  'log' => true
);
```

Also doing this **add 'test' to your $Email variable** like,**

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('test');
```

Comment: thanks buddy, I have no idea what is host here? and user name password here are of server or my email id's ?

Comment: also here you have used two settings public $smtp = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret'
); and public $test = array(
  'log' => true
); , so can we use single setting here ?

Comment: I have tried gmail here ang its giving me error , SMTP Error: 534 5.7.14 54 f2sm19285370pbg.44 - gsmtp

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Comment: The host would be, the email host, for example if your trying to send from gmail the host would be "ssl://smtp.gmail.com", and the public $test is there to only send the email to your cakephp logs to test if it worked. Also, the username/password would be your gmail username/password which your trying to send the email from.

Comment: While your debugging the issue, check the cakePHP error log which is located app/webroot/tmp/logs/error.log and if your on linux run tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log  this is your apache error log :)

Comment: Edit your answer to demonstrate the use of email configuration as `$Email = new CakeEmail('myConfig');`.In this case, `smtp`